# Looking for a tool that is able to automatically paste a password securely

Tags: windows-10

[redacted for privacy reasons]

Answer (score 1):

I think you're personally overcomplicating this process...I'd just switch from KeePassXC to a more integrated and supported password manager. I use to use KeePassXC on my Windows Desktop integrated with Strongbox (iOS Premium version of KeePassXC) for seamless syncing from an encrypted (cryptomator) drive and it got old quick.

I personally switched and started using https://1password.com/. You can utilize keybindings as well detailed here: https://support.1password.com/keyboard-shortcuts/. It is pretty highly customizable and can even integrate with the SSH Agent on Windows and supports keypasses + yubikey integration. I don't type a password here to access my database...I use a yubikey.

***However:*** If you're absolutely set on utilizing KeePassXC and not switching, I'd recommend purchasing a yubikey and you can set it up in a way which will basically "remember" your password for you and type it out with a simple touch.

How this works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bh5Nf8sT6NE

Comment: @Danthalion Bitwarden support isn't good, but there's 0 reason why you'd be unable to log in except for entering wron password to the app.